# How to substract ISOdates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way to calculate timedifferences from two ISOdates with the help of moment.js?

Comment: You can even calculate it without `moment.js`..

Comment: Could you please give me an example with moment js - I walked through the api but have difficulties to implement it.

Comment: Can you provide at least a not-working sample?

Comment: var duration = moment.duration(runwayExitDate.diff(runwayThresholdDate));

Comment: What's the expected result? What's the value of `runwayExitDate` and `runwayThresholdDate`? Please edit your question..

Comment: I would like to have the result in seconds. Input is for example: RWYExit: 2016-04-06T17:49:18.000Z and RWYThreshold: 2016-04-06T17:47:24.000Z

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113285/discussion-between-choz-and-marc).

Comment: @Marc—don't post additional information in comments, edit the question. Questions without code or obvious attempts at code will likely not get answered quickly or well.

Answer (score 0):

with momentjs:

```
moment('Mon May 30 2016 08:00:00.000Z GMT+0200 (CEST)').diff('Mon May 30 2016 07:00:00.000Z GMT+0200 (CEST)');
```

without momentjs:

```
new Date('Mon May 30 2016 08:00:00.000Z GMT+0200 (CEST)').getTime() - new Date('Mon May 30 2016 07:00:00.000Z GMT+0200 (CEST)')
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) docs.

You can get diff between two dates with this snippet:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

If you want the diff in days, you can use this one:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
var m1 = moment('2016-04-06T17:49:18.000Z');
var m2 = moment('2016-04-06T17:47:24.000Z');
var diffSeconds = (m2.diff(m1)) / 1000;
```

Or alternatively in pure JS, but not really cross-browser friendly.

```
var date1 = new Date('2016-04-06T17:49:18.000Z');
var date2 = new Date('2016-04-06T17:47:24.000Z');
var dateDiff = date2 - date1;
var dateDiffSeconds = dateDiff / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasonable answers here, but know that the `.diff()` function in moment accepts a unit parameter. As such, the following will get you the difference between two ISO dates in seconds:

```
moment('2016-01-01T12:25:32').diff('2016-01-01T22:13:16', 'seconds')
-35264
```

Alternately, you can provide a moment to diff instead of a string:

```
var a = moment('2016-01-01T22:13:16'); 
moment('2016-01-01T12:25:32').diff(a, 'seconds')
-35264
```

Or a JS Date:

```
moment('2016-01-01T12:25:32').diff(new Date(), 'seconds')
-12940577
```

If you like. you can use many other unit sizes as well:

```
moment('2016-01-01T12:25:32').diff('2016-01-01T22:13:16', 'hours')
-9

moment('2016-01-01T12:25:32').diff('2016-04-01T22:13:16', 'months')
-3
```